# Soundcloud and JQuery version

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

I'm just getting started with using Soundcloud, and I'm building a simple player to stream a couple of tracks. So I started by looking at some simple examples, like the one on Soundcloud's documentation:

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "id"
  });

  $("#stream").live("click", function(){
    SC.stream("/tracks/239", {autoPlay: true});
  });
</script>

<input type="button" href="#" id="stream" class="big button" value="play" />
```

After figuring out you need to include JQuery for it to work, I did so, locally, but the player failed to stream any sound.

So I looked around and found someone who had a working example online, and saw they were calling version 1.4 of JQuery, but from the Google repository. I tried that instead and it worked. But If I call a different, more recent version, the script doesn't seem to work. I find this a little odd.

Any idea why and how I can fix this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: jQuery changes, functionality gets deprecated/changed with each version. You can either wait for them to update the sdk (If they plan on updating it) or try and debug the code using the console to see what is breaking it.

Comment: The `.live` event has been deprecated.  Check out this page for help updating: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: If the soundscloud API library is not compatible with the latest jquery version there is not much you can do besides running your own [soundmanager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) and getting the data you need yourself.

Comment: Or see whether soundcloud has a non jquery version.

Comment: I just checked the soundcloud sdk, but I don't see any reference to jquery. Are you sure it uses it (besides that simple click eventlistener you could easily do without jquery)?

Comment: Hello! @Jason Sperske, you're 100% correct. The .live event was indeed the culprit. I changed the code and now everything's working correctly. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the .live event is deprecated in more recent JQuery versions. Changed the code to:

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "id"
  });

  $("#stream").click(function(){
    SC.stream("/tracks/239", function(sound){ 
      sound.play();
    });
 });
</script>
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue. Thank you for the replies.